# Unable to connect to MongoHQ in Heroku after updating Mongoid to 3.0.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mongoid, mongohq

I have upgraded my configuration to RoR 1.9.3 and can't get it to work anymore in Heroku.

`config/mongoid.yml` contents:

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
    options:
      skip_version_check: true
      safe: true
```

Error:

```
2012-09-19T16:50:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Mongoid::Errors::NoSessionsConfig (
2012-09-19T16:50:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Problem:
2012-09-19T16:50:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   No sessions configuration provided.
2012-09-19T16:50:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Summary:
2012-09-19T16:50:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   Mongoid's configuration requires that you provide details about each session that can be connected to, and requires in the sessions config at least 1 default session to exist.
2012-09-19T16:50:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Resolution:
2012-09-19T16:50:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure that you have a top-level sessions key with at least 1 default session configuration for it. You can regenerate a new mongoid.yml for assistance via `rails g mongoid:config`.
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

My indenting was wrong, this is the fixed version:

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
      options:
        skip_version_check: true
        safe: true
```